# LeetCode 552: Student Attendance Record II

Tags: c++, beginner, algorithm, programming-challenge, c++17

I'm posting my code for a LeetCode problem copied here. If you have time and would like to review, please do so. Thank you!

### Problem

> Given a positive integer n, return the number of all possible
> attendance records with length n, which will be regarded as
> rewardable. The answer may be very large, return it after mod 109 + 7.
>
> A student attendance record is a string that only contains the
> following three characters:
>
> - 'A' : Absent.
> - 'L' : Late.
> - 'P' : Present.
>
> A record is regarded as rewardable if it doesn't contain more than one
> 'A' (absent) or more than two continuous 'L' (late).
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> - Input: n = 2
> - Output: 8
>
> #### Explanation:
>
> There are 8 records with length 2 will be regarded as rewardable:
>
> - "PP" , "AP", "PA", "LP", "PL", "AL", "LA", "LL"
> - Only "AA" won't be regarded as rewardable owing to more than one absent times.
> - Note: The value of n won't exceed 100,000.

#### Accepted Code

```
class Solution {
public:
    static int checkRecord(int edges) {
        if (edges == 0) {
            return 1;
        }

        // possible candidates
        uint32_t adj_matrix[MATRIX_WIDTH_SQUARED] = {
            1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
            1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
            0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
        };

        uint32_t a[MATRIX_WIDTH_SQUARED];
        uint32_t b[MATRIX_WIDTH_SQUARED];
        uint32_t* accumulated = a;
        uint32_t* temp = b;
        uint32_t* adj_matrix_pointer = adj_matrix;

        std::memset(a, 0, sizeof(a));

        for (unsigned int node_x = 0; node_x < MATRIX_WIDTH_SQUARED; node_x += MATRIX_WIDTH + 1) {
            a[node_x] = 1;
        }

        // Square 
        while (edges > 1) {
            if (edges & 1) {
                matrix_multiply(accumulated, adj_matrix_pointer, temp);
                std::swap(temp, accumulated);
            }

            matrix_multiply(adj_matrix_pointer, adj_matrix_pointer, temp);
            std::swap(temp, adj_matrix_pointer);
            edges >>= 1;
        }

        matrix_multiply(adj_matrix_pointer, accumulated, temp);
        uint64_t first_col_sum = 0;

        // Sum up
        for (int node_y = 0; node_y < MATRIX_WIDTH_SQUARED; node_y += MATRIX_WIDTH) {
            first_col_sum += temp[node_y];
        }

        return (uint32_t) (first_col_sum % MODE);
    }

private:
    static constexpr int MATRIX_WIDTH = 6;
    static constexpr int MATRIX_WIDTH_SQUARED = MATRIX_WIDTH * MATRIX_WIDTH;
    static constexpr uint64_t MODE = 1000000007UL;

    static void matrix_multiply(uint32_t* a, uint32_t* b, uint32_t* c) {
        for (unsigned int node_y = 0; node_y < MATRIX_WIDTH; node_y++) {
            for (unsigned int node_x = 0; node_x < MATRIX_WIDTH; node_x++) {
                uint64_t matrix_multi = 0;

                for (unsigned int k = 0; k < MATRIX_WIDTH; k++) {
                    matrix_multi += (uint64_t) (a[node_y * MATRIX_WIDTH + k]) * (uint64_t) (b[k * MATRIX_WIDTH + node_x]);
                    matrix_multi %= MODE;
                }

                c[node_y * MATRIX_WIDTH + node_x] = matrix_multi;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

#### Reference

In LeetCode's answer template, there is a class usually named `Solution` with one or more `public` functions which we are not allowed to rename.

- [Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/student-attendance-record-ii/)
- [Discuss](https://leetcode.com/problems/student-attendance-record-ii/discuss/)

Comment: I suggest you try some of the problems on https://www.hackerrank.com/ to get a little more attention to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use C++ Container Classes**
This code looks too much like C code and not enough like C++ Code.

In the modern day C++, the use of raw pointers such as `uint32_t* accumulated = a;` are frowned upon, and container classes such as `std::array` and iterators were developed to reduce the use of raw pointers.

The C style array `b` is never initialized, and the C style array `a` is initialized twice.

```
        std::memset(a, 0, sizeof(a));

        for (unsigned int node_x = 0; node_x < MATRIX_WIDTH_SQUARED; node_x += MATRIX_WIDTH + 1) {
            a[node_x] = 1;
        }
```

The first initialization can be accomplished by:

```
        uint32_t a[MATRIX_WIDTH_SQUARED] = {0};
```

and I would prefer to see an iterator used in the second initialization.

**Use Proper Casting**
Currently the code is implementing C style casting (`(uint32_t) (first_col_sum % MODE)`) which is not as type safe as either [static_cast(VALUE_TO_BE_CAST)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) or [dynamic_cast<NEW_TYPE>(EXPRESSION)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast). In this case I recommend `static_cast`.

**Static Functions**
It is not clear why the `checkRecord()` function was changed to a [static member function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) since the original prototype was `int checkRecord(int n)` in the question. There really is no need for it to be static.

> By declaring a function member as static, you make it independent of any particular object of the class. A static member function can be called even if no objects of the class exist and the static functions are accessed using only the class name and the scope resolution operator.

**Variable Names**
The symbolic constant names are clear as are the variable names `adj_matrix` (adjacency would be clearer), `accumulated` and `adj_matrix_pointer`, but the variable names `a`, `b` and `temp` are not clear and leave someone who has to read or maintain the code guessing.

**Complexity**
The function `checkRecord()` is too complex (does too much). After the if statement there should be a call to a function to execute the rest of the code, and that function might cal sub functions. Remember that it is much easier to write correct code when you limit what a function is responsible for.

There is also a programming principle called the Single Responsibility Principle that applies here. The [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) states:

> that every module, class, or function should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality provided by the software, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by that module, class or function.